# my RecyclerView is stack to the end but it don't show tow items of the end

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I'm using a recyclerview in my bottom sheet and it stack to the end, but this doesn't show the last items, and I must scroll down to see them-all.

Any one have any idea?

```xml
<LinearLayout ...
     android:id="@+id/comment_sheet"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:behavior_hideable="true"
     app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/article_comments"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
               android:background="@color/indigo_50" />



        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/input_comment"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:minHeight="50sp"
               android:maxHeight="100sp"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:hint="@string/enterYourComment"
               android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I also use

```
Lm.stackfromend(true);
```

Comment: Use this articleComments.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1), after setting adapter and  data to adapter.

Comment: using constraintLayout will solve many problems like this and simillar to this, although there is some ways to handle it by linearLayouts. But I recommend you trying constraintLayout.